# Is there a way to make a default implementation on a protocol on Swift?

Tags: swift

So I have this protocol

```
protocol Syncable {
    func sync()
}
```

then I want to create another protocol which implements the first one but also specifies other functions to implement like this:

```
protocol Repository:Syncable {

    func propagateTop()
    func propagateLow()

    override func sync() {
        propagateTop()
        propagateLow()
    }
}
```

So in this way the ones who implement `Repository` have to implement the two functions without the need of knowing or implementing the `sync` one.

Is there anyway to force this?

I tryed making `Repository` a class and make subclasses of it for every `Repository` I want, but that doesn't force that every subclass should implement that 2 methods.

Comment: The Swift programming language guide has a [nice and concise section on protocol extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521) (and protocols in general) which I would definately recommend having a read of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could write an `extension`:

```
protocol Repository: Syncable {
    func propagateTop()
    func propagateLow()
}

extension Repository {
    func sync() {
        propagateTop()
        propagateLow()
    }
}
```

A type implementing `Repository` will get the default implementation of `sync()`. They could still provide a specialized implementation. However, the type will not be able to use the default `Repository.sync` in the specialization.